# Previous NSDictionary now to JSON array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
- (void)retrieveData
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"***/connection.php"];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    _json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    _questionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < _json.count; i++)
    {
        NSString * qID = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * qTitle = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"question_title"];
        NSString * qA = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"A"];
        NSString * qB = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"B"];
        NSString * qC = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"C"];
        NSString * qD = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"D"];
        NSString * qAnswer = [[_json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"question_answer"];

        question * myQuestion = [[question alloc] initWithQuestionID:qID andQuestionName:qTitle andQuestionA:qA andQuestionB:qB andQuestionC:qC andQuestionD:qD andQuestionAnswer:qAnswer];

        [_questionsArray addObject:myQuestion];
    }

    [_json enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *questionDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        //Here I'm treating the index like an NSNumber, if your code is expecting a string instead use
        //@(idx).stringValue
        [_questions setObject:questionDictionary forKey:@(idx)];

        //or the modern equivalent
        //questions[@(idx)] = questionDictionary;

        //If you want to use your 'questions class' then create one and put it into the array instead of the dictionary pulled from the array.
    }];

    NSLog( @"%@", _questions );

}
```

Logs (null)

random gobledy gook so my post isn't mostly code
random gobledy gook so my post isn't mostly code
random gobledy gook so my post isn't mostly code
random gobledy gook so my post isn't mostly code
random gobledy gook so my post isn't mostly code

Comment: Did you have a question?  Like Jeopardy, everything must be in the form of a question.

Comment: @HotLicks My question is basically how I can do what I was doing with the dictionary, now I'm bringing in the data in JSON. It's the first time I've attempted this, and the app I'm developing relies on it. So it's paramount I manage to do it. So before I could access the dictionary inside a dictionary and use a simple counter to move to the next key for the next question. Whereas now, I don't know how the array looks for a start, and bring all 40 questions in at once is proving to confuse me. I'm unsure whether to retrieve a question i.e limit 1 per question use it that way,slow performance

Comment: You don't know how the array looks?  You know you can simply NSLog it.  An NSLog of NSArrays/Dictionarys looks remarkably similar to the source JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it becomes something like this

```
self.questions = .... //I assume this is the array you reference 'question' objects that is created by your retrieve data method

//this used to be created by pulling an object out of your questions dictionary with the key i interpreted as a string.
//now that it's an array you should be able to just reference it by index, assuming they were inserted in order
//I'm also assuming that what comes out of the aray is a question object given the code you provided with the signature
//- (id) initWithQuestionID: (NSString *) qID andQuestionName: (NSString *) qName andQuestionA: (NSString *) qA andQuestionB: (NSString *) qB andQuestionC: (NSString *) qC andQuestionD: (NSString *) qD andQuestionAnswer: (NSString *) qAnswer
Question *nextQuestion = self.questions[i];


self.answer = nextQuestion.questionAnswer;
self.questionLabel.text = nextQuestion.questionLabel;
//and so on
```

I also suggest the following edit to replace your for loop.  It uses a for in loop instead, this saves you from having to keep track of an index and looks cleaner.  It also helps so you don't keep repeating the [_json objectAtIndex:i] chunk of code.  I also use modern objective-c syntax to access the dictionary.

```
for (NSDictionary *questionDictionary in _json)
{
    NSString * qID = questionDictionary[@"id"];
    NSString * qTitle = questionDictionary[@"question_title"];

    ...
    question * myQuestion = [[question alloc] initWithQuestionID:qID andQuestionName:qTitle andQuestionA:qA andQuestionB:qB andQuestionC:qC andQuestionD:qD andQuestionAnswer:qAnswer];
    [_questionsArray addObject:myQuestion];
}
```

If you need the key along with the object in the dictionary then you can clean it up in a similar way with the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

```
[_json enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    //your code here
}];
```

EDIT

It sounds like what your really wanting to do is to pull down your JSON but keep all your other code the way it was when you were using a dictionary that you got from your plist.  So in this case you want your parsing function to return a dictionary instead of an array.  If that's the case it's worth sidestepping into computer science for a second.

NSDictionarys are also known as a hash, map, symbol table, or associative array.  Some languages (such as Lua) don't have an array collection like NSArray, they only have dictionaries.  From a dictionary you can create many of the other collections your used to like arrays (and sets too).  Heres how it works:  Instead of an ordered collection of elements with an index, you place the items in a dictionary and use what would have been the index as the key, and the value becomes, well, the value.  For example an array and it's equivalent associative array (aka dictionary):

```
NSArray *array = @[@"hello", @"world", @"!"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@(1): @"hello",
                             @(2): @"world",
                             @(3): @"!"};
```

This is exactly what your doing when you load in the data from your plist because the first elements key is 0 followed by another dictionary, and I'm supposing that the next element in the list is 1 followed by another dictionary.  Inside your parsing function it becomes

```
NSMutableDictionary *questions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_json enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *questionDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //Here I'm treating the index like an NSNumber, if your code is expecting a string instead use
    //@(idx).stringValue
    [questions setObject:questionDictionary forKey:@(idx)];

    //or the modern equivalent
    //questions[@(idx)] = questionDictionary;

    //If you want to use your 'questions class' then create one and put it into the array instead of the dictionary pulled from the array.
}];
```

This of course assumes that your api is going to return the JSON questions in the order you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when the database is retrieved it retrieves 40 database rows, and could potentially take more depending on what i choose to do,  So when I'm trying to print a question, how it used to work is move to dictionary key, display everything from it, then next question to the next key, whereas now I have what would appear to be 7 * 40 keys to work with? so can I not parse it into a dictionary to use it the same way I'm already using it?

Comment: Or would it be easier for me to output an XML/plist format in php and retrieve the information from there to be able to use my current dictionary method?

Comment: Updated with another example that I think answers your question.

Comment: my json/php retrieval takes 40 random rows from the database, and outputs them as "ID","QuestionTitle","A","B","C","D","Question Answer" so using the method you've provided it will create the dictionary index 0 for the first set of questions like above, then will move on to index 1 for the next set of questions?

Comment: yes.  It will take the first row of "ID","QuestionTitle","A","B","C","D","Question Answer" and place it in the dictionary with key 0, then move onto the second one and place it at key 1 and so on until all rows are added.

Comment: Thank you very much, if you wouldn't mind just advising me on which parts of my code are now depreciated? And I'm assuming this will fall into my retrieveData method

Comment: That's pretty tough given you haven't provided all your code.  I would guess the array related stuff in your retrieve data method as well as it's associated c style for loop would go.

Comment: Okay, so the loop creating _questionsArray will go. I've implemented your method and my code is expecting a string for the index, so do I change it to this? `[_json enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *questionDictionary, NSString * (idx).stringValue, BOOL *stop) {` ?

Comment: No, don't try and modify the parameters to the block.  use this line [questions setObject:questionDictionary forKey:@(idx).stringValue];

Comment: ANND sorry to be a pain, but I NSLog the dictionary after using the method to fill the dictionary and it logs (null) I'll update my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56483/discussion-between-brandon-roth-and-daniel-watson).